# Does a charge moving freely in an electric field's direction, produce a magnetic field?

Tags: electrostatics, magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, conservative-field

Does a charge moving freely in an electric field's direction, produce a magnetic field? If so, then why is energy conserved in cases of distance of closest approach? If there is a magnetic field it is non conservative, so how is this possible? I tried to find out but could not find the reason for it.

Comment: I think you got some good answers there. The system is conservative if we include the electromagnetic radiation that is being produced. If we don't, then there is indeed an energy loss due to the neglected radiation term.

Comment: The electron is not only an electric charge, it is a magnetic dipole too. As you can make an electric field by separating charges by electric potential, you can make a magnetic field by aligning the magnetic dipoles of the electrons (permanent magnet). So a movement of charges is not neccessery for a macroscopic magnetic field.

Answer (score 2):

The moving charge *will* produce a magnetic field in the lab frame of reference. Since the charge is actually accelerating it will also emit electromagnetic radiation.

So the charge *will* be losing energy. "[T]hen why is energy conserved in cases of distance of closest approach?" Strictly, it isn't, but we assume that the accelerations are small enough for the loss of energy to be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, let's look at the Lorentz force equation:

$$\mathbf{F}=q(\mathbf{E}+\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B})?$$

From this, we can see that a force will be applied to the charge *regardless* of its motion if it is inside an electric field. Since charges produce electric fields of their own, this then means the electric field will now have a time dependence.

Then given Ampere's law:

$$\nabla\times \mathbf{B}=\mu_{0}(\mathbf{J}+\epsilon_{0}\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t})$$

We can say that a spatially-variant magnetic field will be produced.

Answer (score -2):

If an electron moves perpendicular to a magnetic field, it creates an electromagnetic field.

[image: Electromagnetic field]

Nevertheless, it doesn't explicitely create the magnetic field, it would already be there. For example: planet Earth.

[image: The Earth's magnetic field]

Furthermore, an electron and a proton creates an electric field, as in this image:

[image: +Q -Q electric field]

If one is double the charge, and they are opposite:

[image: +2Q -Q electric field]

And if they are both equal charges:

[image: +Q +Q electric field]

Finally, if you add the magnetic field (in blue) to the electric fields (in orange), you get these graphs:

**Electromagnetic field caused by the charges +Q and -Q:**
[image: +Q -Q electromagnetic field]

**Electromagnetic field caused by the charges +Q and +Q:**
[image: +Q +Q electromagnetic field]